# Why is return not needed in this case?

Tags: java

i'm new to programming and i'd like to ask that why is it that in my code i do not need to use a return function in the constructor and method?

Also why is it that after using the yearPasses function age is increased by 3 and not 1?

Apology for the lengthy code

```
public class Person
{
    private int age;

    public Person(int initialAge)
    {
        // Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge
        if (initialAge<0)
        {
            System.out.println("Age is not valid, setting age to 0.");
            initialAge = 0;
            age = initialAge;
        }
        else
        {
            age = initialAge;
        }
    }

    public void amIOld()
    {
        if (age<13)
        {
            System.out.println("You are young.");
        }
        else if (age>=13 && age<18)
        {
            System.out.println("You are a teenager.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You are old.");
        }
    }

    public void yearPasses()
    {
        age = age + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        int age = sc.nextInt();
        Person p = new Person(age);
        p.amIOld();
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            p.yearPasses();
        }
        p.amIOld();
        System.out.println();
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you think you need a `return`?

Comment: 1) The constructor initializes the class, it's not supposed to return anything. 2) There's a for loop which runs `yearsPasses()` 3 times.

Comment: Constructors may not have a return type hence no return

Comment: You're explicitly calling `yearPasses()` 3 times. What did you expect would happen??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a `return` in the constructor because a constructor's job is to create an object. The `new` operator returns that object for you, so it doesn't need to be in the constructor itself.

Your other methods are declared with a return type of `void`, which means they don't return anything, so you don't need `return` statements in those either.

You're calling `yearPasses` in a loop that executes three times.

Comment: The constructor's job is not to create an object. Its job is to initialize the object.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors create the object, the `new` keyword is where the object is returned.

All your other methods are labelled as `void`, meaning they do not return anything.

You could add a return to your `yearPasses` method, that will return the new age if you want, however it depends on what you need it to do. (This is just an example of using the return)